# Maple Error: final value in for loop must be numeric or character

Tags: maple

I have this simple procedure in Maple that I want to plot.

```
test:=proc(n)
    local i,t;  
    for i from 1 to n do
        t:=1;
    od;
    return t;
    end:
```

The procedure itself works fine.

```
> test(19)
                               1
```

When I want to plot I get the following Error:

```
> plot(test(x),x=1..10)
Error, (in test) final value in for loop must be numeric or character
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Maple's usual evaluation model is that arguments passed to commands are evaluated up front, prior to the computation done within the body of the command's own procedure.

So if you pass `test(x)` to the `plot` command then Maple will evaluate that argument `test(x)` up front, with `x` being simply a symbolic name.

It's only later in the construction of the plot that the `plot` command would substitute actual numeric values for that `x` name.

So, the argument `test(x)` is evaluated up front. But let's see what happens when we try such an up front evaluation of `test(x)`.

```
test:=proc(n)
  local i,t;  
  for i from 1 to n do
    t:=1;
  od;
  return t;
  end:

test(x);
Error, (in test) final value in for loop
must be numeric or character
```

We can see that your `test` procedure is not set up to receive a non-numeric, symbolic name such as `x` for its own argument.

In other words, the problem lies in what you are passing to the `plot` command.

This kind of problem is sometimes called "premature evaluation". It's a common Maple usage mistake. There are a few ways to avoid the problem.

One way is to utilize the so-called "operator form" calling sequence of the `plot` command.

```
plot(test, 1..10);
```

Another way is to delay the evaluation of `test(x)`. The following use of so-called unevalution quotes (aka single right ticks, ie. apostrophes) delays the evaluation of `test(x)`. That prevents `test(x)` from being evaluated until the internal plotting routines substitute the symbolic name `x` with actual numeric values.

```
plot('test(x)', x=1..10);
```

Another technique is to rewrite `test` so that any call to it will return unevaluated unless its argument is numeric.

```
test:=proc(n)
  local i,t;
  if not type(n,numeric) then
    return 'procname'(args);
  end if;
  for i from 1 to n do
    t:=1;
  od;
  return t;
end:

# no longer produces an error
test(x);

        test(x)

# the passed argument is numeric
test(19);

           1

plot(test(x), x=1..10);
```

I won't bother showing the actual plots here, as your example produces just the plot of the constant 1 (one).

Answer (score 0):

@acer already talked about the technical problem, but your case may actually have a mathematical problem. Your function has Natural numbers as its domain, i.e. the set of positive integers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...} Not the set of real numbers! How do you interpret doing a for-loop for until a real number for example Pi or sqrt(2) to 5/2? Why am I talking about real numbers? Because in your plot line you used `plot( text(x), x = 1..10 )`. The `x=1..10` in `plot` is standing for x over the real interval (1, 10), not the integer set {1, 2, ..., 10}! There are two ways to make it meaningful.

1. Did you mean a function with integer domain? Then your plot should be a set of points. In that case you want a points-plot, you can use `plots:-pointplot` or adding the option `style=point` in `plot`. See their help pages for more details. Here is the simplest edit to your plot-line (keeping the part defininf `test` the same as in your post).

```
plot( [ seq( [n, test(n)], n = 1..10 ) ], style = point );
```

And the plot result is the following.

[image]

2. In your function you want the for loop to be done until an integer in relation with a real number, such as its floor? This is what the for-loop in Maple be default does. See the following example.

```
t := 0:
for i from 1 by 1 to 5/2 do
    t := t + 1:
end do;
```

As you can see Maple do two steps, one for `i=1` and one for `i=2`, it is treated literally as `for i from 1 by 1 to floor(5/2) do`, and this default behavior is not for every real number, if you replace `5/2` by `sqrt(2)` or `Pi`, Maple instead raise an error message for you. But anyway the fix that @acer provided for your code, plots the function "x -> test(floor(x))" in your case when x comes from rational numbers (and float numbers ^_^). If you change your code instead of returning constant number, you will see it in your plot as well. For example let's try the following.

```
test := proc(n)
  local i,t:
  if not type(n, numeric) then
    return 'procname'(args):
  end if:
  t := 0:
  for i from 1 to n do
    t := t + 1:
  end do:
  return(t):
end:
plot(test(x), x=1..10);
```

Here is the plot.

[image]

It is indeed "x -> test(floor(x))".